# Assigning One Name to multiple DataFrame Columns

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with feature vectors in machine learning that vary in length; some are scalars, others are vectors. I represent one feature vector as the entire row in a Pandas DataFrame object. Suppose I have some DataFrame that I created using:

```
Feature_Matrix = pd.DataFrame(Data,columns=['feat1','feat2'...,'featN'])
```

Now suppose that 'feat1' corresponded to some scalar C and 'feat2' is a vector with values [M,N] , then how can I have it such that calling

```
Feature_Matrix
```

returns some sort of array in the following form:

```
         'feat1',        'feat2'
 Image 1 [  C1   ,    M1    ,   N1   , ....]
 Image 2 [  C2   ,    M2    ,   N2   , ....]
         ...
```

I need it such that if I index into Feature_Matrix as such:

```
Feature_Matrix['feat2']
```

then it returns

```
Image 1 [[M1,N1],
Image 2  [M2,N2],
         ...]]
```

Comment: So what are you asking for? How to filter the df like `Feature_Matrix[Feature_Matrix['feat1'=='C']]`?

Comment: Well your updates make no sense to me, you need to explain clearer how you are distinguishing your data, preferably with representative input data and an example usage showing output data

Comment: So when you do Feature_Matrix['feat2'] what doesn't it give you?

Comment: I realized that I simply have to name each column 'feat2' and it extracts what I need, that is, all the columns under the name.